# Access 'select rows between' query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a basic query in access. The SQLlooks like:

```
SELECT tblAssignedWords.ChildID, tblAssignedWords.Child, tblAssignedWords.WordID, tblAssignedWords.Word, tblAssignedWords.Status, tblAssignedWords.WordDifficulty, tblAssignedWords.WeekNumber
FROM tblAssignedWords
WHERE (((tblAssignedWords.ChildID)=1));
```

This pulls through 70 records. I only want to see records on rows between 10 and 20 (10 records in total). Is there and SQL statement i can use to see only these rows?

Thanks

Craig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort of.  You need to have some measure of the ordering.  Let me assume this is `WordId`:

```
SELECT top 10 *
from (SELECT top 20 aw.ChildID, aw.Child, aw.WordID, aw.Word, aw.Status,
             aw.WordDifficulty, aw.WeekNumber
      FROM tblAssignedWords aw
      WHERE aw.ChildID = 1
      ORDER BY WordId
     ) t
ORDER BY WordId Desc;
```

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly. I just need to be able to turn it into an append query to append all records to a new table....

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tblAssignedWords.ChildID, tblAssignedWords.Child, tblAssignedWords.WordID, tblAssignedWords.Word, tblAssignedWords.Status, tblAssignedWords.WordDifficulty, tblAssignedWords.WeekNumber
FROM tblAssignedWords
WHERE tblAssignedWords.ChildID between 10 and 20
```

use this